# How to avoid from invalidating the signature after adding the content on PDF?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation

Trying to add content on signed PDF, but after adding the content the signatures get invalid.

Comment: Yes because, the signed certificate contains the hash of the whole file for the security of its integrity and when you add contents to it, the hash value stated in the signature differs from its actual hash. Thus, the signature gets invalid.

Comment: That's the whole point of signing. A valid signature indicates that the document has not been modified after it was signed. If you can modify it without invalidating the signature, the signature mechanism is broken.

Comment: ok,is there any other way to resolve this issue??

Comment: Yes, modify it and then get it signed again. Or strip off the signature itself.

Comment: What kind of content do you wish to add? I assume you are talking about integrated signatures. When the content of a PDF is changed in append mode, a small selection of possible changes is considered valid.

Comment: Images(.jpg,png) kind of data i want to add on pdf.

Comment: @NKhan In general adding content to a signed PDF breaks the signature; guaranteeing that the PDF represents what the signer signed, after all is what signing is all about. That being said, depending on the type of signature, certain additions (mainly form fill-ins and annotations) may be allowed. Thus, would stamp annotations fulfill your requirements? And what kind of integrated signatures do you have? (Furthermore, please mention the name of the user you address in a comment, otherwise he likely will not get a notice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures

As explained in the comments by mkl, the changes you can make depend on the MDP settings of the previous signature(s). Adding extra content to a content stream is explicitly forbidden, but in some cases you can add:

- form fields
- annotations
- extra signatures

This is all explained in the book mentioned above (I wrote it, you can download it for free).